# Paypal IPN Testing - Making Locally Hosted Site Accessibile Externally

Tags: apache, paypal, localhost, port, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to setup Paypal IPN listener. I need Paypal to be able to "see" my locally hosted website in order to test this before going live. What I've done so far, from reading around is:

1. Ensured Apache was listening to port 80, using: Listen 80 in httpd.conf. I'm using AMPPS
2. Opened port 80 on my firewall
3. Tested it on canyouseeme.org to ensure it was open
4. Found my computer's IP address using cmd.exe then ipconfig to get the IPv4 address
5. Set up port forwarding on my router to port 80, using this IPv4 address as the internal host
6. Set up an account at no-ip.com, let's say it's mysite.no-ip.biz, so that I could access my computer through that rather than my internet IP address
7. Downloaded their client so that my dynamic IP is automatically updated and will continue to be accessible through mysite.no-ip.biz
8. Visited hidemyass.com to access "mysite.no-ip.biz" to see what an external user sees
9. I can now see adminer.php and a cgi-bin folder

None of which I could have done before. But now I'm stuck. I normally access my site locally by loading AMPPS and it's configured so that I can go to www.mysite.local/ in my browser.

How do I enable it to be "seen" externally and test this given the previous steps I've gone through? I feel like the dog in the "I have no idea what I'm doing" meme, but I've tortured myself enough: once more unto the Stack, dear friends.

EDIT:
I have now added this to httpd.conf, below Listen 80:

```
<VirtualHost mysite.no-ip.biz> //also tried <VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot c:/users/../../../../public_html
ServerName mysite.local
</VirtualHost>
```

But it's still not working. hidemyass.com still resolves in the adminer.php and cgi-bin folders in the apache directory when I enter the URL mysite.no-ip.biz I have the line

```
 Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

in httpd.conf and the vhosts file contains a number of other virtual hosts set up by AMPPS. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you can access mysite.no-ip.biz and see your IPN listener, then that's the URL you can use for IPN.
If it doesn't show the documents however, you'll want to reconfigure Apache to listen for that specific domain (or edit your existing httpd.conf or 'default' site to listen on all domains).

I would suggest taking a look at [VirtualHost Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) on the Apache site.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /www/example1
     ServerName www.example.com

     # Other directives here </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /www/example2
     ServerName www.example.org

     # Other directives here 
 </VirtualHost>
```

> The asterisks match all addresses, so the main server serves no requests. Due to the fact > that the virtual host with ServerName www.example.com is first in the
>   configuration file, it has the highest priority and can be seen as the
>   default or primary server. **That means that if a request is received
>   that does not match one of the specified ServerName directives, it
>   will be served by this first VirtualHost.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can access mysite.no-ip.biz from hidemyass.com (proxy) but can't see the documents to access the IPN listener. To check my understanding in httpd.conf I would put: <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot C:/users....(local machine path)
     ServerName www.mysite.local/</Virtualhost> Is that right?